# ConvertFrom-StringData values stored in variable

Tags: hashtable

I'm new to Powershell and I'm putting together a script that will populate all variables from data stored in a Excel file.  Basically to create numerous VMs.

This works fine apart from where i have a variable with multiple name/value pairs which powershell needs to be a hashtable.

As each VM will need multiple tags applying, i have a column in excel called Tags.
The data in the field would look something like: "Top = Red `n Bottom = Blue".

I'm struggling to use ConvertFrom-StringData to create the hashtable however for these tags.
If i run:

ConvertFrom-StringData $exceldata.Tags

I end up with something like:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Top                            Red `n bottom = blue

I need help please with formatting the excel field correctly so ConvertFrom-StringData properly creates the hashtable.  Or a better way of achieving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, formatted the excel field as:  Dept=it;env=prod;owner=Me

Then ran the following commands.  No ConvertFrom-StringData required.

```
$artifacts = Import-Excel -Path "C:\temp\Artifacts.xlsx" -WorkSheetname "VM"
foreach ($artifact in $artifacts) { 
$inputkeyvalues = $artifact.Tags
# Create hashtable
$tags = @{}
# Split input string into pairs
$inputkeyvalues.Split(';') |ForEach-Object {
# Split each pair into key and value
$key,$value = $_.Split('=')
# Populate $tags
$tags[$key] = $value
}
}
```